# how to configure pytest to get the exceptions summary after the logs

Tags: python, pytest

By default, pytest hides the stdout/stderr logs during the test execution, and only shows them after the failure summary. Is there a way to swap the order? Specially when there are many failures and long logs, I always gets confused because I expect to find them in "chronological" order : first the logs and finally the error which aborted the test

I played with log_cli, show_capture and capture flags, but I didn't find any way.

```
============================================================================================ FAILURES ============================================================================================
___________________________________________________________________________________________ test_error ___________________________________________________________________________________________
test/utils/test_collections.py:15: in test_error
    assert False
E   assert False
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is a warning
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is an error
```